# Is there a way to add the table name automatically using SqlDataAdapter.Fill

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqldataadapter

I'm using the IDbDataAdapter Interface to fill my dataSet from a SQLite database. Unfortunatelly the Fill function sets the the DataTable names "Table, Table1. Table2, etc.".
I have multiple databases and tables the best way is to fillt the DataTalename automatic with the Fill function. Without thes correct tablenames the .Update function isn't working as well.

1. In the most manuals there using Fill(table, "tableName") but the only function in the IDbAdapter is the Fill(table) function.
2. I set the MissingSchemaAction to AddWithKey and the MissingMappingAction to Passthrough

Both doesn't change the table names in the created DataSet.

Is it possible to set the database table names automatic using the .Fill function?

Comment: You hand over an existing table to the fill method so simply name the table via the constructor of the DataTable.

Comment: You talk about a created DataSet. Fill does not create one. Is your naming problem  created earlier when setting up the DataSet?

Comment: I create an empty DataSet and pass it to the Fill function. The Fill function create DataTables but not with the tablenames from the database.

Comment: Can you switch to programm against DbDataAdapter instead of the interface? The Fill method you presumably want to use are implemented in that class and not surfaced via the interface.

Comment: Thank you I found this part. It would be perfekt if the Fill function could fill the DataTable names in the DataSet automatic from the database. But in this case I think this is not possible.

Comment: You can provide the name yourself if you get access to the method just not simply via the Interface. If you expect some extraction from the given Query/Sql Statement i assume even the most clever algorithm has a less then 50/50 chance on doing that right. At least you couldn't rely on those. There can be multiple tables involved. The different statement might use different tables or none. I could read from a View/Stored Proc and update on a table. Heck you don't even need a table behind the query to generate data and return it via the QueryStatement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping.

I found a way do solve my problem. Ralf got me the perfect hints.

In my case I define the DataTableName depending on the given sql string. After that I can use the TableMappings from the DataAdpater to map the name to the used Table. In this case I can use the interface to guarantee dependency injection.

And second I forgot to create the specific CommandBuilder object.

Problem soveld :)